# How to write BitArray to Binary file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.5

I have a BitArray and I want to write that to a binary file. I would prefer to see the value in hex before i write it to the output file.
I tried this:

```
writebyte=a._getbytes()
fo.write(struct.pack(">h",writebyte))
```

(where a is the BitArray and fo is the output file)

Any ideas on how to proceed with this?

Answer (score 0):

Bitarray has a method that should work for this.

```
with open('filename', 'wb') as fo:
    a.tofile(fo)
```

As an alternative, you should be able to open the file in binary mode and write the bytes to it.

```
with open('filename', 'wb') as fo:
    fo.write(a.tobytes())
```